# I Have Problem Installing Extensions For Visual Sudio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I Have A Problem And That Is :

I've Tried To Install An Extension From Visual Studio 2019 Extension Manager's MarketPlace
e.g (CodeMaid)

So I've Clicked And Downloaded It , When I've Restarted Visual Sudio To Install That Extension But Installer Said : `The Install Of "CodeMaid" Extension For Visual Studio Was Not Successful for All the selected products.For More Information Click On The Install Log Link at the bottom of the dialog.`]

Note That I Have Installed My Visual Studio In My H: Drive.

Please Help Me :(

I've Tried Any Extension To Install But They All NOT Installed Successfully e.g I Tried To Install Resharper But The Resharper Can't Detect My Visual Studio

(Sorry for My Bad English)
I Have The Screenshot Here:
[Click Here To Open Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTXKl.png)

Comment: Any details in the log?

Comment: @gdir Yes , I Have It => [Click To Download](http://uupload.ir/view/nd5g_mylog.log/)

Comment: Try to repair your Visual Studio installation.

Comment: @ERAGON please don't link the file, but add the relevant text to your post.

Comment: the Problem Is Fixed , I've Uninstalled VS And Reinstalled It With Some More  Free Spaces On C: Drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install extension with .vsix file. Firstly, go to https://open-vsx.org/ and download the extension that you want.After downloading you will get VSIX file.Final step: open visual studio and go to EXTENSIONS.Click option icon(•••) and find and click (install from VSIX) and then choose your downloaded .vsix file. Done.

Answer (score 0):

> I've Tried Any Extension To Install But They All NOT Installed
>   Successfully e.g I Tried To Install Resharper But The Resharper Can't
>   Detect My Visual Studio

Please try these steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**1)** delete all vs componment caches under `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxxx\ComponentModelCache` and do not forget to delete all the files under `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp`

**2)** disable any third party extensions under Extensions-->Manage Extensions to prevent any other extensions affect it.

**3)** run VS as administrator and then install the extension again.

**4)** [do a repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in VS Installer

**5)** If your VS2019 is not the latest version, please update it to the latest version and please update your OS at the same time.

**In addition**, if all the steps does not work, l suggest you chould **reinstall** VS2019 and you would better install VS2019 on the default system disk. And there is [a similar issue](https://github.com/tomasr/viasfora/issues/274).

After you uninstall VS2019, please check if you have this:`%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe`.

If so, please launch it from an admin command prompt with a `-full` param: `InstallCleanup.exe -full`

If not, please manually delete the `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer` folder

Then relaunch `vs_enterprise.exe` and then install VS2019.